# How to use directlabels to label lines in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, direct-labels

```
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)
mydat <- structure(list(Name = c("Ana", "Josh", "Bart", "Ana", "Josh", 
"Bart"), color_line = c("purple", "purple", "orange", "purple", 
"purple", "orange"), x = c(0.864864864864865, 0.810810810810811, 
0.472972972972973, 0.851351351351351, 0.702702702702703, 0.648648648648649
), y = c(0.702702702702703, 0.675675675675676, 0.797297297297297, 
0.797297297297297, 0.72972972972973, 0.635135135135135), Class = c("A", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "B")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

mydat
   Name color_line         x         y Class
1:  Ana     purple 0.8648649 0.7027027     A
2: Josh     purple 0.8108108 0.6756757     A
3: Bart     orange 0.4729730 0.7972973     A
4:  Ana     purple 0.8513514 0.7972973     B
5: Josh     purple 0.7027027 0.7297297     B
6: Bart     orange 0.6486486 0.6351351     B
```

I have the above data set, and I plotted the results as follows:

```
g <- ggplot(mydat, aes(x = x, y = y, color = Class)) + 
       theme_classic() + 
       geom_line(mapping = aes(group = Name), color = mydat$color_line) + 
       geom_point() + 
       scale_color_manual(values=c("springgreen4", "royalblue3"))
g
```

[image]

Now, I would like to add the `Name` of each individual to each line. Something that might look like this:

[image]

The closest thing that I found is the `angled.boxes` in `library(directlabels)`. You can see how it looks [here](https://tdhock.github.io/directlabels/docs/lineplot/posfuns/angled.boxes.html).

However, when I tried the following, I got a different plot.

```
direct.label(g, "angled.boxes")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to use the `geomtextpath` package which adds lots of options to add direct labels to lines and even allows for curved text. For your use case you could simply replace `geom_line` by `geomtextpath::geom_textline` to add your labels.

Note: Additionally I slightly adjusted your code to make use of the `color` aes for the lines and the `fill` aes to color the points.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(geomtextpath)

pal_color <- c("purple", "purple", "orange")
names(pal_color) <- c("Ana", "Josh", "Bart")

pal_fill <- c("springgreen4", "royalblue3")
names(pal_fill) <- c("A", "B")

base <- ggplot(mydat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = pal_color) +
  scale_fill_manual(values= pal_fill) +
  theme_classic() +
  guides(color = "none")

base +
  geomtextpath::geom_textline(
    aes(group = Name, color = Name, label = Name), textcolour = "black") +
  geom_point(aes(fill = Class), shape = 21, stroke = 0, size = 2)
```

[image]

Or using the `offset` and `gap` arguments you could add the labels on top of the lines:

```r
base +
  geomtextpath::geom_textline(
    aes(group = Name, color = Name, label = Name),
    offset = unit(5, "pt"), gap = FALSE, textcolour = "black") +
  geom_point(aes(fill = Class), shape = 21, stroke = 0, size = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. this is perfect! Just a follow up question, how can one change the width of the lines?

Comment: You could set the line width with the `linewidth` aes or argument, i.e. `geomtextpath::geom_textline(..., linewidth = 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal, but I did this a long time ago using some math and manual adjustments

```
mydat %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  mutate(
    posx = mean(x)*1.01,
    posy = mean(y)*1.01,
    angle = -60*diff(range(y))/diff(range(x))
    ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, color = Class)) + theme_classic() +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(group = Name), color = mydat$color_line) +
  geom_point() + scale_color_manual(values=c("springgreen4", "royalblue3"))+
  geom_text(aes(x = posx, y = posy, group = Name, label = Name, angle = angle),
            size = 6, show.legend = FALSE, color = "black")
```

[image]